# Does Evolve use horizontal or vertical FOV?

Tags: evolve

I try to use `107` horizontal FOV in every game I play, [around the same as in Valve games](http://www.casualhacks.net/Source-FOV-calculator.html) (16:9 monitor). `107` in [Evolve](http://store.steampowered.com/app/273350/) is far higher, the world looks warped. Does Evolve use [vertical FOV](http://www.rjdown.co.uk/projects/bfbc2/fovcalculator.php)?

Answer (score 2):

Better FOV controls in Evolve is a feature players always asked for.

If you are using only one monitor 16:9 try to set your FOV near 90 and adjust it to your comfort. Just with the Monster I was able to use a higher FOV without affect gameplay negatively.

The game was made with low FOV in mind (60 if I remember well) and when they update it with a FOV slider it was to deal with multiple monitors setup or to wide wide screens (21:9).

I used to set my FOV at 120 in almost all games, but some of them affect really bad hit detection when you shoot.

Comment: Some games use "raycast" to detect a hit from your weapon: when you click, it "shots" a invisible ray from something in your char, to where your mouse is pointing in the screen. Then they check if that ray hit an enemy, floor, wall, props.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/0koWg.jpg
If the point of origin in the game don't scale well with the FOV/Screen size you can miss your shoot even if you aim is in the target.